# Problemas de conexión por ssh en kali linux a usuario root

Tags: linux, ssh

Buenas tengo 2 maquinas virtuales de kali linux y estoy tratando de conectarme a una con otra con el "ssh -L 1234:10.0.2.8:22 root@10.0.2.8" pero al momento de intentar ingresar la contraseña de la maquina objetivo en la maquina atacante me sale el mismo error una y otra vez
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren diferentes razones.

1. En tu archivo de configuración `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` hay una entrada que es

   ```
   PermitRootLogin no
   ```

   Que en algunas ocasiones viene con el valor `no`. Cambiala a `yes`, y de paso le das una revisada al campo `PasswordAuthentication` y ves el valor que tiene, después reinicia el servidor ssh con `sudo service ssh restart`.

   Y listo, con esto ya podría estar funcionando.
2. Crea tu par de llaves con `ssh-keygen` y pon la llave pública de la máquina 1 en la máquina dos. Si no sabes cómo hacer esto, es sencillo.

   Después de ejecutar el comando `ssh-keygen` y dar "enter" a todo, se crea un archivo en la carpeta `~/.ssh` que se llama `id_rsa.pub`. La ruta varía según con qué usuario ejecutaste ese comando, aunque la expansión `~` resuelve según el caso. A veces puede estar en `/home/tu_usuario/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, o si la creaste con el usuario `root`, está en `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. En el caso que sea, el comando `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` te imprimirá el valor en la terminal.

   Ya que tengas el valor en la terminal, añade ese resultado en el archivo `/home/usuario_que_desees/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Si lo que quieres es entrar a fuerza con el usuario `root`, es en el archivo `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Si no existe el archivo, créalo. Pero te recuerdo que, a pesar de poner tu llave pública en las claves autorizadas, no siempre podrás entrar como `root` a menos que la entrada del archivo `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` tenga la entrada `PermitRootLogin` con el valor `yes` (para que puedas entrar con contraseña o con la llave pública) o `prohibit-password` (para que puedas entrar sólo con llave pública). Haz las modificaciones en caso de que no diga eso y luego reinicia el servidor ssh de la computadora 2 con `sudo service ssh restart`.

   Si quieres entrar como otro usuario que no sea root, ignora lo anterior de modificar el archivo de configuración y sólo pon la clave en el archivo `.ssh/authorized_keys` de ese usuario.

   **Es importante que esa cadena de texto (tu archivo id_rsa.pub) de tu computadora 1 esté "igual" en el archivo de authorized_keys**

   #### ¿Cómo pasar tu llave pública de una máquina a otra?

   A mi, muy al inicio me resultaba engorroso. Pero puedes hacerlo desde una usb, tu correo, un chat o con `netcat`. Netcat permite abrir sockets de red.

   Primero revisamos que ambas máquinas tengan `netcat` (que varía el uso entre la versión de openbsd o la tradicional).

   Suponiendo que las dos máquinas están en la misma red, ejecuta en la primer máquina

   ```
   nc -l 0.0.0.0 -p 2222
   ```

   Y en la segunda máquina

   ```
   nc <ip_primer_maquina> 2222
   ```

   Y comienza a escribir, se tienen que ver las palabras de lo que pase en una computadora en la otra, es como un pequeño chat. Esto funciona si no tienes un firewall bloqueando esos puertos.

   Si funcionó, entonces ya puedes pasar la llave pública de la computadora 1 a la 2 ejecutando en la computadora 2 lo siguiente para que lo que reciba lo escriba en el archivo `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   ```
   nc -l 0.0.0.0 -p 2222 > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   Y en la computadora 1 envías la llave pública a la computadora 2 con

   ```
   nc <ip de la computadora2> 2222 < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   Si el proceso tarda mas de 2 segundos, oprime `Ctrl+C`.

   Si no sabes la ip local de tu computadora (para aquellos lectores que aplique el caso) puedes ejecutar alguna de las siguientes instrucciones `hostname -I` o `ifconfig` o `ip addr`.

   En caso de que no tengas `netcat`, busca otra forma. La manera "formal" de hacerlo es con el comando `ssh-copy-id` pero como no puedes ingresar desde un inicio, entonces no funciona de esta manera.
3. Puede sonar tonto pero revisa que la contraseña la tengas bien escrita, tal vez puede que hayan cambiado la distribución de tu teclado y se escriban otros caracteres en su lugar. También revisa que la ip sea la correcta.

Comment: gracias, ahora no estoy en la pc, en otro momento intento y te aviso